# epoxy grout in contact with regular sanded cement grout

Tags: grout, cement, epoxy

We don't have a floor threshold between the bathroom floor and the corridor. is it a bad idea to grout the bathroom floor with epoxy grout and the rest regular grout? what happens if the epoxy grout gets mixed with cement grout during the work? the guys do not want to wait till the epoxy entirely dry then grout it.

Answer (score 2):

It's OK to do that. The epoxy grout is great for bathrooms because it doesn't stain, is virtually waterproof and it's not affected by the cleaning supplies you'd usually find in a bathroom. The installers need to do the epoxy grout first and let it set up. It needs to stay in the bathroom because the sheen will be different than the regular grout so you don't want it to be worked into a hallway. Once the epoxy group has hardened, but not completely, they can use the regular grout right up against the epoxy group which will not absorb any moisture from the regular grout... .enjoy your new tile.

Comment: I have done similar and agree the epoxy is best done first. If the standard grout is well cured it wouldn’t hurt if the epoxy was 2nd. I would tell them if the uncured grout has a reaction because they did not let it set they will be redoing it. They can do the epoxy then start in a different area of the hall the epoxy sets fairy quick. But they will have to be careful not to get any of the slurry from the regular grout on the epoxy (I used blue 2” painters tape to help, there is a difference in shade but it’s not bad.+

Comment: How long would it take the epoxy to harden - enough to start the cement grout? the guys tend to rush not sure how to manage them. we are using Mapei Kerapoxy CQ http://www.mapei.com/public/US/products/3000150-kerapoxy-cq-en.pdf